# jQuery function only working once when jquery .load is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery .load() function to load external .html files into my index.html page.

Here is my index.html:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav"></div>





<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>


    $(function() {

        $("#nav").load("nav.html");

    });



    function changeLayout(layout) {

        if(layout == '4') {

    $("[class^='col-md-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-md-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("col-md-4");



} else

        if(layout == '6') {

    $("[class^='col-md-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-md-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("col-md-6");



}

else

        if(layout == '12') {

    $("[class^='col-md-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-md-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("col-md-12");



}

}


</script>




</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the nav.html file that I'm loading:

**nav.html**

```
<div id="subnav" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-wrapper">
            <div class="layout">
                <button onclick="changeLayout('4');">Layout1</button>
                <button onclick="changeLayout('6');">Layout1</button>
                <button onclick="changeLayout('12');">Layout1</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the changeLayout function above will only work 'Once' and then I would need to reload the whole page to get it to work again.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `type="button"` to your buttons currently your `buttons` seem to be `submitting` the page.

Also no need for `href` attribute in buttons.

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeLayout('4');">Layout1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeLayout('6');">Layout1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeLayout('12');">Layout1</button>
```

Move you `changelayout` function to `nav.html`

Comment: @estevangomez can u check console if there is any error ?

Comment: @estevangomez can you show html of you `nav` page ?

Comment: The source code is the same as the one I've posted above in the question. .load() include the html into the DOM so source code will not show the included html

Comment: But you will have the html of `nav.html` file can u share that ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the question

Comment: OK got it move your function `changelayout` into `nav.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your scripts in the HTML head section. Just move both of your script tags in the head section (below title) and you should be fine.

I guess you replaced the content of your body with the loaded html file - so all your JavaScript was gone.

Comment: Tried it and I still have the same issue...Didn't sort the problem